# Is there a way to modify an array with another array?

Tags: python, numpy

Im trying to modify a single dimension of a numpy array- using another array. However, I get pretty non-intuitive results unless I use a for loop.

```
state = np.zeros((7, 7, 1))
state2 = np.zeros((7, 7, 1))
sample = np.array([ 1,  2,  0,  1,  2,  1,  0])
b = np.ones((7, 1))
time_index = 0

state[np.arange(state.shape[0]), time_index + sample[:, np.newaxis], 0] += b
for i, s in enumerate(sample):
    state2[i, time_index + s, 0] += b[i]
```

I was expecting `np.array_equal(state, state2) == True`, however `state` doesn't seem to be doing what I expect. How would I recreate `state2` in a vectorized way?

Comment: what are you trying to do here, what do you mean by modifying `state2` while expecting `np.array_equal(state, state2) == True`

Comment: Im trying to recreate `state2` without using a for loop. Namely by modifying the vectorized code for `state`

Comment: Then why not `state2[np.arange(state2.shape[0]), time_index + sample[:, np.newaxis], 0] += b`?

Comment: Skip `[:, np.newaxis]` and use flattened `b` : `b.ravel()`.

Comment: @divakar if you want to add that as an answer, happy to mark it officially!

Comment: Would encourage you to post your own answer, hopefully with some explanation upon research if needed.